# Make exception to non-word character split

Tags: java, regex

I have the following regex:

```
\s+|(?=[^\w'])|(?<=\W)(?=')
```

Which I use in java as:

```
String[] split = str.split("\\s+|(?=[^\\w'])|(?<=\\W)(?=')");
```

This basically allows me to split words based on blank spaces, special characters and leaves an exception for apostrophes, so that I can keep the contents inside apostrophes without splitting it.

This works great when there is a normal character inside the apostrophes:

```
Input:
write('A')

Output:
write
(
'A'
)
```

However, if there is a special character inside the apostrophes, it does not work properly:

```
Input:
write('A','(', '=', ',');

Actual output:
write
(
'A'
,
'
(
'
,
'
=
'
,
'
,
'
)
;

Wanted output:
write
(
'A'
,
'('
,
'='
,
','
)
;
```

Is there a way I can make an exception for skipping special characters - basically not skipping them if they are inside apostrophes?

Here is my Regex101: https://regex101.com/r/mL7eL6/3

Comment: As far as I can see, this goes beyond the capabilities of regular expressions. You will need at least a lexical analyzer, like [JFlex](http://www.jflex.de/), or [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/).

Comment: Just match and capture what you need and only match what you do not need. Once your requirements get that complex split won't help.

Comment: [*Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I'll use regular expressions.”  Now they have two problems.* - Jamie Zawinski](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that I'm taking some guesses regarding the grammar of the language you're trying to parse:

One approach is to use lookahead to determine whether the number of apostrophes from the current position to the end of the string is even.  If it can be assumed that the apostrophes are balanced, positions where this number is even are 'outside' apostrophes.  The regular expression (in Java) that such the counting is:

```
String[] split = str.split(
    "\\s+|"+
    "(?=[^\\w'][^']*('[^']*'[^']*)*$)|" +
    "(?<=[^\\w'])(?=[^']*('[^']*'[^']*)*$)|" +
    "(?=('[^']*'[^']*)*$)|" +
    "(?<=')(?=[^']*('[^']*'[^']*)*$)"
);
```

The first alternative ignores whitespace.  The second and third split the string before and after, respectively, on (non-apostrophe) special characters but only when the number of apostrophes in the remainder of the string is even.  Similarly, the fourth and fifth alternatives split the string before and after, respectively, balanced apostrophes.

However, using this approach has at least three drawbacks:

1. It's not very efficient.  The lookaheads have an end of string anchor which will result in lots reading to the end of the string.
2. It balances apostrophes right-to-left instead of left-to-right, which might be surprising.  (Of course, this is only a problem on malformed input.)
3. The regex is complicated.

Using Patterns and Matchers might be the better option.  Instead of designing a regex that determines where to split the string, the regex specifies the parts of the string of interest:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(
    "[\\w]+|" +
    "[^\\w']|" +
    "'[^']*'");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

The first alternative picks out strings of alphanumeric characters.  The second picks out single non-alphanumeric that are not apostrophes.  The third picks out balanced apostrophes.  `matcher.find()` finds the next part of the input that matches the regular expression, if any. `matcher.group()` returns the substring last matched by `matcher.find()`.

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth explanation, this made a lot of sense!